# Pass user input (parameters) in the query string (SqlCommand.CommandText), without getting a VS code analysis warning

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlparameter, prepared-statement

I think the main point of my question is: what is best practise or is Visual Studio 2019 giving me wrong hints about reviewing the query string?

I have checked [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2100?view=vs-2022) example from Microsoft where the warning-code is sent me, but the following warning keeps popping up. The example gives obsolete code so I might look in the wrong place..

[Review if the query string passed to 'string SqlCommand.CommandText' in 'GetTrumpfCadCamDocuments', accepts any user input.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXujJ.png)

The code was different, but when I do it the way the docs suggest the code looks like this:

```cs
/// The sqlfilepath is a content file which looks like this:
/// SELECT * FROM [R_DOCUMENT] WHERE [TYPE] = @type
/// Writing out the file content as a string is also used sometimes
/// which gives the same error.

string query = File.ReadAllText(sqlfilepath);

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
    {
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", type);
        command.CommandText = query; //warning gets triggered here
        
        .....
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual value of `query`?

Comment: Where is `query` coming from? If it is a constant then you shouldn't get this error. If it's coming from an input parameter or concatenation then you should question why that is. The warning is there for a reason: beware of SQL injection. Side point: a shorter syntax is: `using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))` also you don't need to `Close` as the `using` sorts that out

Comment: Aside... [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: Yes Charlie normally I use the shorter syntax which is not used by msdn. I've added where query comes from.